# HTTP: Параметры пути

Tags: http

Изучаю [RFC 2068 — Протокол Передачи Гипертекста - HTTP/1.1](https://rfc2.ru/2068.rfc)
В описание синтаксиса [URI](https://rfc2.ru/2068.rfc/8#p3.2) есть упоминание параметров пути и параметров запроса.
Кто-нибудь может объяснить(желательно в примерах):

1. Разницу между параметрами пути и параметрами запроса со стороны клиента и со стороны сервера
2. Практическую пользу(или ущербность) от использования параметров пути.

**UPDATE**
[HTTP URL Path Parameter Syntax](https://doriantaylor.com/policy/http-url-path-parameter-syntax) -- разъяснения по синтаксису
[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) -- Описание URI, раздел 3.3. Path (см. последний абзац)

Comment: не хотите привести ссылки на упоминания эти, или процитировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Синтаксис URI **не специфицирует никакого синтаксиса для параметров**, пути и запроса. Он лишь разделяет **путь** и **строку запроса**. Размещение в этих сегментах каких-либо параметров к синтаксису URI уже никак не относится, это особенности реализаций (веб-фреймворков и приложений).

Синтаксис определяет для них набор "подразделителей" (`sub-delims`)::

```
sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

Они не имеют никакой значимости в URI кроме лишь того, что относятся к *зарезервированным символам*, а потому их `%`-экранированные аналоги им не эквивалентны. Это позволяет использовать их в чистом виде в синтаксических конструкциях и в экранированном виде для значений/данных.

Сколько-нибудь широко сейчас используется такая форма параметров в **строке запроса**:

```
http://хост/путь?параметр1=значение1&параметр2=значение2#фрагмент
                 _______________________________________
```

Такую структуру типично называют "query parameters" (параметры запроса).

Обратите внимание, что `&` и `=` есть в `sub-delims`, поэтому названиях и значениях параметров можно использовать `%26` (экр. `&`) и `%3D` (экр. `=`), не ломая стурктуру параметров, при этом получая их после разбора в чистом, неэкранированном виде.

Например, в строке запроса `%26=%3D&%3D=%26` по этому соглашению записаны:

- параметр `&` со значением `=`
- параметр `=` со значением `&`.

---

Что же до **параметров пути**, похоже, что они **практически вымерли**. Мне не довелось работать ни с одним веб-инструментарием, который бы их поддерживал.

Единственная известная мне среда (и с ней я не работал) где я их видел, это Java-сервлеты. Спецификация сервлетов *ссылается* на них, но *не определяет*. Беспорядок.

Одно из применений этого механизма в сервлетах это отслеживание сессий в ситуациях, когда клиент не принимает куки; пример такого URL (спецификация сервлетов оперирует именно URL):

```
http://www.myserver.com/catalog/index.html;jsessionid=1234
                                          ________________
```

С немалой вероятностью, если вы решите их использовать, вам придётся реализовывать их разбор и формирование самостоятельно. Лишние усилия. Существенный минус.

---

Для сервера и клиента в общем случае разницы между ними никакой нет. То есть, это разные сущности, у них разная семантика, но технически они ведут себя однаково. (В отличие от, скажем, фрагмента, который может не передаваться клиентом на сервер вовсе.)

Answer (score 1):

> Что же до параметров пути, похоже, что они практически вымерли.

Возможно, то, что подразумевалось @user181100 под "параметрами пути", и вымерло. Однако параметры пути - это совсем иное.

Наиболее яркий пример, который можно привести, чтобы понять что такое параметры пути (Path Parameters), - это задача проектирования RESTful API.

При проектировании RESTful API параметры пути (Path Parameters) определяют конкретные ресурсы (resources), а параметры запроса (Query Parameters) используются для того, чтобы искать (фильтровать) или сортировать эти ресурсы.

Например, вы проектируете сервис, основной задачей которого является создание, изменение, чтение и удаление данных о  цветах (растениях). Цветы - центральная сущность вашего сервиса. Вы начинаете проектировать конечные точки (endpoints) вашего API и создаете следующую конечную точку:

`/flowers`

Таким образом, вы уже можете выполнять следующие запросы:

`POST /flowers` - создать новый цветок

`GET /flowers` - получить список всех цветов

Далее у вас возникнут следующие вопросы:

- Каким образом получить данные конкретного цветка?
- Каким образом изменить данные конкретного цветка?
- Каким образом удалить конкретный цветок?

Если вы хотите создать по-настоящему RESTful API, вы воспользуетесь параметрами пути (Path Parameters), чтобы ответить на эти вопросы. Тогда ваши запросы станут выглядеть так:

`GET /flowers/<id>`, например, `GET /flowers/185` - получение данных конкретного цветка

`PUT /flowers/<id>`, например, `PUT /flowers/185` - изменение данных конкретного цветка

`DELETE /flowers/<id>`, например, `DELETE /flowers/185` - удаление конкретного цветка

Так как идентификатор конкретного цветка является частью пути, он называется параметром пути.

Вы продолжаете работу над своим API и решаете позволить выполнять поиск цветов по их названию. В этом случае к вам на помощь приходят параметры запроса (Query Parameters). Тогда ваш запрос для поиска цветов, название которых содержит символы `роза`, может выглядеть так:

`GET /flowers?name=роза`

Параметры *пути* (Path Parameters) повсеместно используются при проектировании RESTful API и вряд ли когда-то умрут.